# Firebase Notifiation Token Transfer Wrong to IOS Current Version Swift WebView

Tags: ios, firebase, webview, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are trying to send a notification with firebase in an ios project where we use webview and developed with swift, but token transfer with javascript interface does not work in the current ios version. I have reviewed and tried many examples but it is either not responding at all or giving an unusable error. how can i solve this problem?

**WebView;**

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
struct SwiftUIWebView: UIViewRepresentable{
    let url: URL?
    func makeUIView(context: Context)->WKWebView{
        let prefs = WKWebpagePreferences()
        prefs.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences = prefs
        return WKWebView(
            frame: .zero,
            configuration: config
        )
    }
    func updateUIView( _ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context){
        guard let myURL = url else{
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: myURL)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message:WKScriptMessage){
                print(message)
    }
}
```

**Notification;**

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
var TokenData = "";
//@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    // [START set_messaging_delegate]
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    // [END set_messaging_delegate]
    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
      UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    // [END register_for_notifications]
    return true
  }
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
  }
  // [START receive_message]
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
  }
  // [END receive_message]
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
  // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
  // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
  // the FCM registration token.
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
    // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
  }
}
// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notific
ation: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
  }
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
    completionHandler()
  }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
  // [START refresh_token]
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
    TokenData = String(describing: fcmToken);
    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
```

Comment: Adding the code from your last attempt to send a notification with firebase would help others to help you with your problem. Consider updating your question to add that helpful information.

Comment: Thank you to your suggestion, i added using code.